# Photoshop CC - Making Highlights

Tags: adobe-photoshop, highlights

How would I make the white highlights like what you see in the fingernails of this image?  I've tried several methods but nothing comes out looking this nice.

[image]

Comment: What methods have you tried? It would reduce the number of answers that you don't need if you mention it in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Create a white narrow rhombus shape over the nail

[image: rhombus]

**Menu Filter** > **Blur** > **Gaussian Blur**

[image: blur]

Duplicate the rhombus and scale it

[image: duplicate]

Duplicate and reposition the small rhombus

[image: Duplicate]

Select the three rhombus from each nail, duplicate them, move them to the next nail and rotate them.

**Result**

[image: End]

[Photo](https://unsplash.com/photos/8Z8JijlydJs) from unsplash.com

Comment: How did you create the rhomboid shape?  I've only played with circles, rectangles, etc. in the menu.

Comment: got it - pen tool.

Comment: I made a square, rotate it 45° and scale it horizontally.

Comment: instead of a rhombus couldn't it be just an ellipse? Way simpler to draw.

Comment: That hand looks like it's way too big to belong to that face '^_^